Find max consecutive days with no sales in SQL
DBMS I am using is Teradata.
I have a table called Sales, with columns:
Store, Item, DT, and Volume
This is a daily sales table, where Store and Item are numbers, and DT is a date.
Now, it could be the case that if a store/item combo did not have any sales for a certain date, that it could have no entry in the table, or its entry has a 0 as the value for volume. It is imperative that I consider both cases.
I would like to calculate the max consecutive days with no sales for a store/item combo, where the date range is between '2023-12-31' and '2024-03-30'
This is what I have come up with, but it unfortunately does not consider many cases:
SELECT 
    sq.STORE,
    sq.ITEM,
    MAX(sq.Consec_No_Sales_Days) AS Max_Consec_No_Sales_Days
FROM (
    SELECT 
        STORE,
        ITEM,
        DT - LAG(DT) 
        OVER(ORDER BY STORE,ITEM,DT) AS Consec_No_Sales_Days
    FROM
    SALES

    WHERE
    SALES.VOLUME > 0
    AND DT BETWEEN '2023-12-31' AND '2024-03-30'


    GROUP BY
    STORE,
    ITEM,
    DT
) sq

WHERE 
    sq.Consec_No_Sales_Days > 0 
GROUP BY
    sq.STORE,
    sq.ITEM


Can you clarify the requirements / cases not covered, and maybe supply some example data and desired results? For example, if something sold 2023-12-01 and then again 2024-01-01, what would you want as Consec_No_Sales_Days? Same question for something that sold 2024-03-01 and then not again by 2024-03-30? And what about things that did not sell at all during the period in question - do those need to be included?

If you are fetching the data for a specific period ('2023-12-31' -'2024-03-30') and you have the data before start of period then what would be previous sales date for the STORE/ITEM having first sale within period on '2024-01-10' ???
NOTE: In such a case the code below takes start of the period as previous sales date (using Coalesce function). The same has been done with end of the period against next sales date. If that is not ok - you should make the appropriate adjustment to meet your needs.
/*  SALES table sample data
     STORE       ITEM DT             VOLUME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        10        101 2023-11-30         12
        10        101 2023-12-31         10
        10        101 2024-01-25         21
        10        103 2024-03-25         32
        10        103 2024-03-30         10
        20        107 2024-01-30         54
        20        107 2024-02-12         23
        20        109 2024-03-01         43    
        30        110 2024-01-10         17   */

Create inner query that excludes null or zero VOLUME rows and fetches just the rows within period (Where clause). Without null/zero volume rows LAG()/LEAD() Over() analytic functons will work ok if partition by and order by parts are ok. There is also a date math calculating DAY_DIFF column described in NOTE above. Outer query just aggregates and groups the resultset of the inner query.
--      S Q L :
SELECT    STORE, ITEM, Max(DAY_DIFF) AS MAX_DAY_DIFF
FROM    ( Select    STORE, ITEM, DT, VOLUME, 
                     GREATEST( DT - Coalesce( LAG(DT) Over(Partition By STORE, ITEM Order By DT), To_Date('2023-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ),
                               Coalesce( LEAD(DT) Over(Partition By STORE, ITEM Order By DT), To_Date('2024-03-30', 'yyyy-mm-dd') ) - DT ) AS DAY_DIFF
          From      sales
          Where     Coalesce(VOLUME, 0) > 0 And 
                    DT Between DATE '2023-12-31' And DATE '2024-03-30'
        )
GROUP BY  STORE, ITEM
HAVING    Max(DAY_DIFF) > 0
ORDER BY  STORE, ITEM

/*        R e s u l t : 
     STORE       ITEM MAX_DAY_DIFF
---------- ---------- ------------
        10        101           65
        10        103           85
        20        107           47
        20        109           61
        30        110           80  */


This works, for the most part. The exception: Suppose an item only had one day with sale, on Jan 10. It seems that code will return 10 days, however I want it to return 80 days; (End of date range) - Jan 10 = 80.

@feonyte Just updated the answer. The same logic with end of period. Get GREATEST value of the two.
